# Adding Horizontal Scrolling to Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

Under `#tabs`, I have a number of different navigation links placed horizontally next to one another. When I have my zoom set to 100%, a couple of the links are hidden. How would I add a horizontal scrollbar to `#tabs` to show all navigation links without having to zoom out to view all of them.

I have tried adding `overflow-x: auto` and `whitespace: nowrap` to `#tabs` with no luck. It creates a vertical overflow however I am trying to achieve a horizontal overflow.

Attached is my code:

```css
/*
    ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2020.
*/

html > body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* Navigation */
#navigation {
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 40px;
    background: #1B315E;
}

.spacer {
    display: block;
    margin: 120px 0 0 0;
}

#navigation > a {
    display: block;
    margin: 12px 0 12px 4px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: #FFF;
}

#navigation > a.selected {
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
}

#navigation > a:not(.selected):hover {
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#navigation > .navLinks {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 2px;
}

#navigation > .navLinks > button {
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* Content */
#content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* Title */
#title {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
}

/* Toolbar */
#toolbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}

/* Tabs */
#tabs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: auto;
    background: #CCC;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 4px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 6px);
}

#tabs > a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #1B315E;
}

#tabs > a.selected {
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#tabs > a:not(.selected):hover {
    color: #1B315E;
    opacity: 0.75;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/* Panel */
#panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    border-left: 6px solid #1B315E;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2020.
-->
<html lang="en-AU">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>List of programmes - Summit</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bec3ffe91b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- External Icon Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/setting.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/styling.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"> <!-- Favicon -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <a href="#" title="Home workspace"><i class="fal fa-home"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Learning workspace" class="selected"><i class="fal fa-book"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Student management workspace"><i class="fal fa-user"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Portal workspace"><i class="fal fa-globe"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Administration workspace"><i class="fal fa-cog"></i></a>
            <div class="navLinks">
            <button title="Quick links"><i class="fal fa-bookmark"></i></button>
            <button title="Log out"><i class="fal fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content">
            
            <!-- Title -->
            <div id="title"><i class="fal fa-list"></i> List of programmes</div>
            
            <!-- Toolbar -->
            <div id="toolbar"></div>
            
            <!-- Tabs -->
            <div id="tabs">
                <a href="#" title="Academic reports"><i class="fal fa-file-chart-line"></i> Academic Reports</a>
                <a href="#" title="Attendance"><i class="fal fa-at"></i> Attendance</a>
                <a href="#" title="Summit messages"><i class="fal fa-comments"></i> Summit Messages</a>
                <a href="#" title="Marks book"><i class="fal fa-percentage"></i> Marks Book</a>
                <a href="#" title="Notices"><i class="fal fa-newspaper"></i> Notices</a>
                <a href="#" title="Programme"><i class="fal fa-book-open"></i> Programme</a>
                <a href="#" title="List of programmes" class="selected"><i class="fal fa-list"></i> List of Programmes</a>
                <a href="#" title="Timetable"><i class="fal fa-calendar-alt"></i> Timetable</a>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <!-- Panel -->
        <div id="panel"></div>
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes CSS Here

```
#tabs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: auto;
    background: #CCC;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 4px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 6px);
    white-space: nowrap; /*Add Here*/
  overflow: auto; /*Add Here*/
}

#tabs > a {
    float:left; /*Remove This*/
    display: inline-block;  /*Add Here*/
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #1B315E;
}
```

```css
/*
    ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2020.
*/

html > body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* Navigation */
#navigation {
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 40px;
    background: #1B315E;
}

.spacer {
    display: block;
    margin: 120px 0 0 0;
}

#navigation > a {
    display: block;
    margin: 12px 0 12px 4px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: #FFF;
}

#navigation > a.selected {
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
}

#navigation > a:not(.selected):hover {
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#navigation > .navLinks {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 2px;
}

#navigation > .navLinks > button {
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* Content */
#content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* Title */
#title {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
}

/* Toolbar */
#toolbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}

/* Tabs */
#tabs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: auto;
    background: #CCC;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 4px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 6px);
    white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

#tabs > a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #1B315E;
}

#tabs > a.selected {
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#tabs > a:not(.selected):hover {
    color: #1B315E;
    opacity: 0.75;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/* Panel */
#panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    border-left: 6px solid #1B315E;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2020.
-->
<html lang="en-AU">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>List of programmes - Summit</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bec3ffe91b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- External Icon Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/setting.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/styling.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"> <!-- Favicon -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <a href="#" title="Home workspace"><i class="fal fa-home"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Learning workspace" class="selected"><i class="fal fa-book"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Student management workspace"><i class="fal fa-user"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Portal workspace"><i class="fal fa-globe"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Administration workspace"><i class="fal fa-cog"></i></a>
            <div class="navLinks">
            <button title="Quick links"><i class="fal fa-bookmark"></i></button>
            <button title="Log out"><i class="fal fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content">
            
            <!-- Title -->
            <div id="title"><i class="fal fa-list"></i> List of programmes</div>
            
            <!-- Toolbar -->
            <div id="toolbar"></div>
            
            <!-- Tabs -->
            <div id="tabs">
                <a href="#" title="Academic reports"><i class="fal fa-file-chart-line"></i> Academic Reports</a>
                <a href="#" title="Attendance"><i class="fal fa-at"></i> Attendance</a>
                <a href="#" title="Summit messages"><i class="fal fa-comments"></i> Summit Messages</a>
                <a href="#" title="Marks book"><i class="fal fa-percentage"></i> Marks Book</a>
                <a href="#" title="Notices"><i class="fal fa-newspaper"></i> Notices</a>
                <a href="#" title="Programme"><i class="fal fa-book-open"></i> Programme</a>
                <a href="#" title="List of programmes" class="selected"><i class="fal fa-list"></i> List of Programmes</a>
                <a href="#" title="Timetable"><i class="fal fa-calendar-alt"></i> Timetable</a>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <!-- Panel -->
        <div id="panel"></div>
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to do this easily.

Give #tabs a `display:flex` property, and a `overflow-x: auto` will do the trick.

I have also removed the `margin-top: auto` from your example.

```css
/*
    ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2020.
*/

html > body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* Navigation */
#navigation {
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 40px;
    background: #1B315E;
}

.spacer {
    display: block;
    margin: 120px 0 0 0;
}

#navigation > a {
    display: block;
    margin: 12px 0 12px 4px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    color: #FFF;
}

#navigation > a.selected {
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
}

#navigation > a:not(.selected):hover {
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#navigation > .navLinks {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 2px;
}

#navigation > .navLinks > button {
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* Content */
#content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* Title */
#title {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
}

/* Toolbar */
#toolbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}

/* Tabs */
#tabs {
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #CCC;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 4px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 6px);
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

#tabs > a {
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #1B315E;
}

#tabs > a.selected {
    color: #1B315E;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#tabs > a:not(.selected):hover {
    color: #1B315E;
    opacity: 0.75;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/* Panel */
#panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    border-left: 6px solid #1B315E;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    ~ Copyright (c) Summit Learning Management System (made by students, for students). 2020.
-->
<html lang="en-AU">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>List of programmes - Summit</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bec3ffe91b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- External Icon Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/setting.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/styling.css"> <!-- Internal Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"> <!-- Favicon -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <a href="#" title="Home workspace"><i class="fal fa-home"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Learning workspace" class="selected"><i class="fal fa-book"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Student management workspace"><i class="fal fa-user"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Portal workspace"><i class="fal fa-globe"></i></a>
            <a href="#" title="Administration workspace"><i class="fal fa-cog"></i></a>
            <div class="navLinks">
            <button title="Quick links"><i class="fal fa-bookmark"></i></button>
            <button title="Log out"><i class="fal fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content">
            
            <!-- Title -->
            <div id="title"><i class="fal fa-list"></i> List of programmes</div>
            
            <!-- Toolbar -->
            <div id="toolbar"></div>
            
            <!-- Tabs -->
            <div id="tabs">
                <a href="#" title="Academic reports"><i class="fal fa-file-chart-line"></i> Academic Reports</a>
                <a href="#" title="Attendance"><i class="fal fa-at"></i> Attendance</a>
                <a href="#" title="Summit messages"><i class="fal fa-comments"></i> Summit Messages</a>
                <a href="#" title="Marks book"><i class="fal fa-percentage"></i> Marks Book</a>
                <a href="#" title="Notices"><i class="fal fa-newspaper"></i> Notices</a>
                <a href="#" title="Programme"><i class="fal fa-book-open"></i> Programme</a>
                <a href="#" title="List of programmes" class="selected"><i class="fal fa-list"></i> List of Programmes</a>
                <a href="#" title="Timetable"><i class="fal fa-calendar-alt"></i> Timetable</a>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <!-- Panel -->
        <div id="panel"></div>
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```